# How to setup Notification Messages in PHP OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, content-management-system

I'm working on CMS with PHP OOP. In this project I have added a feature where admins of a Website can add and manage other admins. In order to add an admin, I have created this page which is called `admin_new.php` and goes like this:

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $groups = $_POST['groups'];
    if($groups == "Main Admin"){
        $level = 1;
    }else if($groups == "Administrator"){
        $level = 2;
    }else if($groups == "Content Creator"){
        $level = 3;
    }else if($groups == "Social Media Manager"){
        $level = 4;
    }else{
        $level = 5;
    }
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $notice['email_validation'] = "The email that you have entered is not a valid one";
    }else{
        $registration = new Register();
        $notices = $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)->getNotices();
    }   
}
?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Add New Admin
            <small>You can add new admin here</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">addnewadmin.php</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Required Information</h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($notice['email_validation'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_validation'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    if(isset($notice['username_exists'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['username_exists'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    if(isset($notice['email_exists'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_exists'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    if(isset($notice['success_message'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-success'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['success_message'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>User name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Temporary password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter password" name="pass" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Group admin</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="groups">
                                    <option value="Main Admin">Main Admin</option>
                                    <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                    <option value="Content Creator">Content Creator</option>
                                    <option value="Social Media Manager">Social Media Manager</option>
                                    <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            Visit <a href="https://zite.pouyavagefi.com/documentation/types.php">admin types</a> documentation to know the differences between each admin.
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

And the class that I had used in this file is called `Register.class.php` and contains this:

```
    <?php 
class Register
{   
    protected $notice = array();
    private $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
        {
            $chk1 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username FROM admins WHERE user_name= ?");
            $chk1->bindParam(1,$username);
            $chk1->execute();
            if($chk1->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                $notice['username_exists'] = "Try different username";
                return $notice;
            }else{
                $chk2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT email FROM admins WHERE email_address= ?");
                $chk2->bindParam(1,$email);
                $chk2->execute();
                if($chk2->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    $notice['email_exists'] = "The email address that you have entered is already exists in database";
                    return $notice;
                }else{
                    $this->NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
                    $notice['success_message'] = "New admin was successfully added";
                    return $notice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
        {
            $reg = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO admins (user_name, email_address, password_hash, group_admin, date_joined, admin_level) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
            $reg->bindParam(1,$username);
            $reg->bindParam(2,$email);
            $reg->bindParam(3,$password);
            $reg->bindParam(4,$groups);
            $reg->bindParam(5,$level);
            $reg->execute();
        }
    }
    public function getNotices()
    {
        return $this->notice;
    }
}
?>
```

Basically all I want to do is to make sure that:

1- Username does not exists in db

2- User didn't enter an email which already exists in db

3- And if everything goes well, then add a new row to the table

And when I run this and fill the form with dummy info to check how to *notices* appear, I get this error message:

**Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNotices() on array in**
**admin_new.php:22**

**Stack trace: addnewadmin.php(20): require_once()**

## 1 {main} thrown in admin_new.php on line 22

And line 22 of `admins_new.php` is this:

```
$notices = $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)->getNotices();
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in concepts.. what is what

`$registration` -> instace of class **Register**
`CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)` -> function which return array **$notice**

> Basically ur method `CheckUname()` returns `$notices` and u call on
>   this array method `getNotices()` and it's problem..

If u wanna get `$notices` u must call public method on `$registration` instance.

```
$registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
$notices = $registration->getNotices()
```

or

```
$notices = $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
```

Comment: Great answer, but the now the problem is, it does not return the $notices

Comment: Can u post here some logs, or is there some logical error?

Comment: Basically no error appear, and the logic works perfectly. But it only does not show the $notice messages

Comment: It should be typo... In *admin_new.php* u set one time *$notice* other time  *$notices* and in error print u have if(isset($notice['username_exists']))... Rewrite $notices on just $notice

Comment: I have changed all the _notices_ to **notice** but still does not solve the porblem :(

Comment: It isn't possible.. Now i try it on my PHP server and it's work correctly.

Comment: You can take a look at _admin_new.php_ here: http://www.paste.org/86160

Comment: Have u require('Register.class.php'); in ur admin_new.php?

Comment: Of course, if it wasn't , it would return the error

Comment: Ach.. Got it... In ur method **CheckUname** *$notice* it's local scope.. Replace it with *$this->notice* :)

I used *$notice = $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);* and this is work..